# Codename One - Layout issue

Tags: codenameone

I've a GUI built app and I set many Icon images in the code for some components.

The thing is I've made sure all "padding" and "margin" values are the same for the different states of the components (unselected, pressed, etc) but when I try to input data into the TextFields, it seems like the dimensions of some components change without notice and they completely mess with my layout.

Even sometimes some of the icons partially disappear. Please see the following screenshot of before and after text input, where the Container and TextFields shrink

[image]

I really don't know what else I can do. I have tried many things, but stil the same outcome. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the container housing all this components scrollable.

Use **Millimeters** for your TextField padding and margin, don't use **Screen Percentage**. From the image in the images you posted, 2mm top and bottom and 1mm left and right would be suitable.

If the components having those icons are pressable like a button, be sure to set their `pressedIcon` to the same icon.

Lastly, style your TextField Unselected state and copy this to Selected and Pressed states, to avoid erroneous styling.

Comment: FYI we fixed this issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1652 which should improve text component selected/unselected styling on device builds

Comment: My test device has a small screen (Samsung S4 mini), so I am afraid when I test the app on a big device (Samsung Note3) the millimeters will make the layout look very different. (Yes Shai, I noticed the fixed issue today. Thanks so much)

Comment: I know how to do this, but I am getting an error so I need your help. 1st: I set the values in SCREEN PERCENTAGE on the GUI Builder. 2nd:on postForm I get all the values of margin and padding using "getMargin(TOP)"...etc and save the pixel values. 3rd: I get the Style of the TextField and then I paste all the Margin and Padding values I collected before into that style. While doing that, I get an error when I try to invoke "setMarginUnit(UNIT_TYPE_PIXELS)". I need that in order to paste the values, which I have in Pixels. Why is it crashing?

Comment: I have a method tfStyle(final TextField testX) where I collect all the values and assign them to a new created Style variable and then I set the style to the TextField. When I run the simulator and go to my TestForm (that has the TextFields) everything goes well. The TextField behave well. But if I try to assign the values to the existing style  "testX.getUnselectedStyle()" I have to invoke "setMarginUnit(UNIT_TYPE_PIXELS)" and when I run the simulator the screen goes completely white  (I want to do the latter so I don't have to be collecting color styles, background styles, etc)

Comment: fixed it!!! The argument was supposed to be an array. So the correct form of the method is setMarginUnit(UNIT_TYPE_PIXELS,UNIT_TYPE_PIXELS,UNIT_TYPE_PIXELS,UNIT_TYPE_PIXELS); The docu showed "byte...marginUnit" instead of "byte[] marginUnit"

Comment: `byte...` is vararg which is technically an array in java so passing 4 arguments will implicitly convert to an array. This was changed from an array recently but should work if you update the client libraries.

Comment: Shai, is it viable to open an issue so that when the elements' padding and margin values are set to "screen percentage", the values don't get affected by the virtual keyboard? (or any other element on the screen, for that matter)